# Mouse wheel Auto scroll to anchor

Tags: javascript

I am looking to implement a script on to a page so that when the user starts to scroll it automatically 'smooth' scrolls' to the next anchor. Almost imitating the one page sliders you see now-a-days.

I have this code from stackoverflow:

http://jsfiddle.net/t6LLybx8/728/

I have tried adding it as JS on to the page using the Visual Composer JS element. had no errors either?

I am new to this, sorry if I sound silly.

Comment: This is example code. Your live code probably is different in a certain aspect. Have you checked if the id's in visual composer match? Can you post a link to your current environment, so we can take a look (or better, post it here, but with live composer it is tricky)

Comment: Yes, I added the a link ID's in which the example has etc. Is there something else I should change? This is the website: http://www.grade1salon.co.uk/

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14524297/how-to-scroll-to-div-after-click-on-about-or-contact-in-my-menu I think that the first answer will help you out.